# NameError: name 'resample' is not defined

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, data-analysis

I am trying to use the resample method in python but getting the below error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-9ff5896e97a3> in <module>
----> 1 df_no_default_downsampled=resample(df_no_deafult,replace=False,n_samples=1000,random_state=42)
      2 df_default_downsampled=resample(df_deafult,replace=False,n_samples=1000,random_state=42)

NameError: name 'resample' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you need [`DataFrame.sample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html):

```
df_no_default_sampled=df_no_deafult.sample(replace=False,n=1000,random_state=42)
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple thing you have to do is to import resample from sklearn

```
from sklearn.utils import resample
df_no_default_downsampled = resample(df_no_deafult, replace = False, n_samples = 1000, random_state = 42)
```